# How can I query any field with MongoRepository

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Assume the domain object (MyDomain) has many fileds (f1, f2, f3 ... f100), define a MyDomainRepository from MongoRepository, I want to take field name and value as parameters instead of hard code the field name as part of query method, like below:

```
List<MyDomain> findByNameAndValue(string name, string value);
```

if the name and value is "f1" and "foo", the method will find all documents whose field "f1" equals "foo".

I have googled hours and no luck.

Any help from anybody, thanks!

Comment: Not possible using Repository method. You have to use MongoTemplate for this

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) predicates.

First, add the following dependencies to your pom.xml (assuming you're using maven to build your project):

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Also add this to your build plugins:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    ...
    </plugins>
```

Your repository must extend QueryDslPredicateExecutor:

```
public interface MyDomainRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDomain, String>,
                                             QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyDomain> { }
```

Your repository will then inherit

```
public Iterable<MyDomain> findAll(Predicate predicate)
```

and a [few other methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QuerydslPredicateExecutor.html).

When you build your project, QueryDSL will generate Q-classes for you, that you can use to programmatically build predicates and query documents matching your predicates:

```
QMyDomain q = QMyDomain.mydomain;
Predicate p = q.f1.eq(value);

Iterable<MydDomain> i = repository.findAll(p);
```

To query your resources using a REST controller, you'll need something similar to:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(/"mydomain")
public class MyDomainController {

    @Autowired private MyDomainRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/search/query")
    public List<MyDomain> query(@QuerydslPredicate(root = MyDomain.class) Predicate predicate) {
        return repository.findAll(predicate);
    }
}
```

This last piece of code is quick and dirty made, it won't probably work as is (at least return some kind of List), but you get the idea.

Comment: I realize this answer is actually more of a "QueryDSL for beginners" than an accurate answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

pvpkiran is right, there is no such thing out of the box. You need to build your own using an injected MongoTemplate, for instance:

```
List<MyDomain> findByNameAndValue(string name, string value) {

    Document document = new Document(name, value);
    Query query = new BasicQuery(document.toJson());

    return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyDomain.class);
}
```

The interesting thing is that you can go a little further and pass several name/value using a Map:

```
List<MyDomain> findByNamesAndValues(Map<String, String> parameters) {

    Document document = new Document(parameters);
    Query query = new BasicQuery(document.toJson());

    return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyDomain.class);
}
```

Just in case, that works with a QueryDSL predicate too:

```
List<MyDomain> findByNamesAndValues(Predicate predicate) {

    AbstractMongodbQuery mongoQuery = new SpringDataMongodbQuery(mongoTemplate, MyDomain.class)
            .where(predicate)
    Query query = new BasicQuery(mongoQuery.toString());

    return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyDomain.class);
}
```

These methods can be further improved to handle pagination, and other cools feature such as field inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: thanks, good points, I am researching MongoTemplate and QueryDSL, because current project uses MongoRepository, thinking of combining MongoTemplate/QueryDSL and MongoRepository if possible (which currently I am not sure).

Comment: I have a project where I use the best of both worlds: repositories that extend MongoRepository  and QueryDslPredicateExecutor (see my other answer) and also custom service classes that use mongoTemplate and QueryDsl. That should give you everything you need to query your data.

Comment: Actually no, the code belongs to the client that pays me :) It basically uses what I've shown in the two answers I gave to this post. I was just emphasizing that you now should have everything needed to solve your problem. But do not hesitate if you have further questions.